# How do I add only one value per line?

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to take a user input and write it to a separate .txt file with only one input per line.

```
vote = input()
fh = open('votedata.txt', 'a')
fh.write(vote)
fh.close
```

When I run my code it saves the input and places it in the txt file, however instead of placing each value on a new line it bunches them together on one. So if I have 5 inputs like 1,2,3,4,5 instead of placing each number on a separate line it bunches them together like 12345. How do I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
vote = input('Enter your vote')
fh = open('votedata.txt', 'a')
fh.write(vote + '\n')
fh.close
```